# How can i convert wsdl to XSD type format?

Tags: xsd, wsdl

I am having XML in wsdl format, now i want to change it's encoding to the format XSD format. Do i need to make some changes in web config, or what i will have to do please suggest me.
below is the Example

```
<wsdl:definitions name="LoginCheck"
                  targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.0.6:8000/LoginCheck.svc?xsd=xsd0"
                        namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.0.6:8000/LoginCheck.svc?xsd=xsd1"
                        namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
```

and I want to convert it to format like below

```
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:saveCharacterAcc">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:saveCharacterAcc">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
            <xsd:complexType name="Character">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="characterNumber"
                                 type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="byteArray"
                                 type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="rotationAngle"
                                 type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="charX" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Comment: Could some body tell me more on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a straightforward way, but you could try using the [wsdl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) tool (or [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) for WCF) to generate C# classes then the [xsd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) tool to generate your XSD from the classes.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I used an XSL transformer with the following XSL code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="wsdl:types">
        <xsl:copy-of select="xs:schema"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wsdl:documentation/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<xsl:template match="wsdl:documentation/text()"/>` tag was used to remove some undesirable text elements, which appeared in my resulting XSD file.